# OrCAD Capture Question: Replace Bias Voltage Marker

Tags: orcad

If you delete a bias voltage box (pictured below), how do you go about replacing them?

[image: Bias Voltage Marker Box]

Comment: There is the VCC icon on your toolbar on the right. Be sure to use the correct net alias.

Comment: I use OrCAD but I'm unsure what a bias voltage box is. Please explain or better still post a picture of one.